# How to use hdfscli python library?

Tags: python, hadoop, webhdfs, pyhdfs-client, python-hdfs

I have following use case,
I wanted to connect a remote hadoop cluster. So, I got all the hadoop conf files (coresite.xml, hdfs-site.xml and others) and stored it in one directory in local file system. I got the correct keytab and krb5.conf file for kerberos authentication. I installed hadoop and placed the untar files under some directory, say `/User/xyz/hadoop`.
I set the following env variables:
`JAVA_HOME(), HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and finally placed my krb5.conf file under `/etc/`. This setup helped me to successfully authenticate using `kinit -kt <keytab> <principal user>` and perform hadoop commands like `hadoop fs -ls /` from my local terminal and access the cluster.

However, I wanted to perform the same action without downloading hadoop. Is there a way? I am using python and came across [this hdfs python library](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). However, I had hard time understanding and working with this lib.

1. What I am trying to achieve, is it possible?
2. If so, what is the right way?
3. Can someone guide me to setup hdfscli lib with right configuration?